# Save & Restore Matrix in GLES20

Tags: opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0

In `GLES 1.0` we can :

```
gl.glPushMatrix();
gl.glTranslatef(...);
gl.glScalef(...);
gl.glTranslatef(...);
gl.glPopMatrix();
```

Now :

```
Save?

Matrix.translateM(...);
Matrix.scaleM(...);
Matrix.translateM(...);

Restore?
```

How i can save & restore matrix in GLES 2.0 ? Maybe in shaders?

Comment: GLES2.0 or GL2.0? Language?

Comment: @Troubleshoot Actually i writing app for android. So in GLES20. I Edited answer.

Comment: @Troubleshoot its 3d. But i draw 2d textures in 3d world.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't push/pop the current matrix stack in OpenGL ES 2.0 because there is not such thing as the matrix stack. You will have to reimplement the equivalent functionality on your own (just like the other matrix-related fixed-function pipeline functions: glFrustum/glMatrixMode/glRotate[df]/glTranslate[df]/...) and eventually update the modelview/projection/... uniform matrix used in each draw call.

To give an idea, here is an example:

```
    class MatrixStack {
         public:
             MatrixStack();

             // Implement functions similar to glPushMatrix()/glPopMatrix()/glMultMatrix()/...
             void push(const Matrix4x4f& m);
             void pop(const Matrix4x4f& m);
             void mult(const Matrix4x4f& m);
             void load(const Matrix4x4f& m);
             void scale(float x, float y, float z);
             void translate(float x, float y, float z);
             void rotate(float angle, float x, float y, float z);

             // Gets a pointer to the raw data of the top matrix
             const float* get() const;

         private:
             stack< Matrix4x4f > m_stack;
    };

    MatrixStack::MatrickStack() {
        m_stack.push(Matrix4x4f::identity());
    }

    void MatrixStack::push(const Matrix4x4f& m) {
        m_stack.push(m);
    }

    void MatrixStack::translate(float x, float y, float z) {
        // Remplace the top matrix of the stack with itself multiplied by the specified translation
        Matrix4x4f m = m_stack.top();
        m_stack.pop();
        m_stack.push(m * Matrix4x4f::translate(x, y, z));
    }

    const float* MatrixStack::get() const {
        return m_stack.top().data();
    }

    // ...

    MatrixStack modelview_matrix_stack;

    // ...

    modelview_matrix_stack.push();
    modelview_matrix_stack.translate(...);
    modelview_matrix_stack.scale(...);

    // Draw something

    // ...
    glUniformMatrix4f(... modelview_matrix_stack.get() ...); // Update modelview matrix
    // ...
    glDrawArrays(...);

    modelview_matrix_stack.pop();

    // ...
```

Comment: But i need to save my matrix state after each scale end. How can i do that without saving state? I edit my answer. Please check again.

Comment: all boils down to simple assignment?

Comment: @deathember What prevents you from creating a stack of 4x4 matrices in your project and doing the push/pop + uniform update yourself?

Comment: So that's all? `tmpMatrix(float4x4) = myCurrentMatrix.clone();` ?

Comment: You copy the matrix you are interested (push). You apply all the operations you want to it (translate/scale/...). You update the corresponding matrix uniform before drawing. Later you can discard this matrix and re-use the original one (pop).

Answer (score 1):

With GLSL shaders, you pass in a matrix as a mat4 uniform variable. Here's a really good tutorial on OpenGL matrices: http://www.opengl-tutorial.org/beginners-tutorials/tutorial-3-matrices/. It pretty much explains everything, however:

- Make sure that you do all the matrix multiplication on the CPU (*i.e* not in GLSL). If you do all the matrix multiplication in GLSL, it will be done with every vertex, which is slower than doing it once per frame on the CPU.

Comment: I see this. But may be i so stupid to understand how that related to my problem. I will edit my answer. Please check again.

Comment: It is related. Using the programmable pipeline you have to handle all the matrix functionality yourself. The tutorial I provided a link to explains how to handle that matrix functionality.

Answer (score 0):

> Now?

```
oldmatrix = Matrix;

Matrix.translateM(...);
Matrix.scaleM(...);
Matrix.translateM(...);

glUniformMatrix4f(…, Matrix);

render_stuff();

Matrix = oldmatrix;
```

Comment: i check this tomorrow

Comment: Yes, matrix was saved, but looks like in second zoom my focal point calculated based on old matrix. How can i fix this? If you want more information or code please tell me.